# how to dynamically set the number of variables in SciPy's optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have this code work fine to optimize multiple variables.

```
def f(params):

    a, b, c = params 
    return a**2 + b**2 + c**2

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Is it possible to modify the code so that the number of parameters can be dynamically passed into f? For example, I'd like to have something like this.

```
def f(params, paramsNumber):
    if paramsNumber == 3:
        a, b, c = params 
        return a**2 + b**2 + c**2
    elif paramsNumber == 2:
        a, b  = params 
        return a**2 + b**2 

if paramsNumber == 3:
    initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
elif paramsNumber == 2:
    initial_guess = [1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the rule is, no matter how many elements are in `params`, the result of `f` should be the sum of the squares of those elements? Can you think of a way to compute that *without* a separate variable for each element? For example, by using a loop?

Comment: And when you set the `initial_guess`, the rule is that it should be a list of `paramsNumber` many elements, and every element is `1`? Can you think of a simple way to create that, without any `if` conditions?

Comment: Thanks, Karl. Basically I need to have the number of variable passed into f, so that I can use either if statement or loop.

Comment: I think you can use a loop no matter how many variables there would be (including zero!). Please try this, and if you think I am wrong, try to explain why clearly, by showing a [mre].

Comment: `initial_guess` determines the shape of the `params` array that `minimize` passes to your function, the `(n,)` of the docs.  Your function can be written in any way that utilizes that array, returning a scalar.  `np.sum(params**2)` should do what you want without explicit unpacking.  (It helps to understand some `numpy` basics to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the params in your objective function, and you can use some general initialization, for your example I simply used numpy ones, that create an array with the given number of ones.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
def f(params):
    return sum(a**2 for a in params)
def find_sol(paramsNumber):
    initial_guess = np.ones(paramsNumber)
    result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess)
    if result.success:
        return result.x
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

```py
find_sol(4)
```

```txt
array([-3.15727582e-08, -3.15727581e-08, -2.06550776e-09, -2.06550765e-09])
```